# Code with generics won't compile

Tags: java, generics

I've failed to google this problem. Why would this line produce a compilation error.

```
wrapper.doSmth(wrapper.getCurrent());
```

I'm using java 7.

```
public class App {
 Wrapper<?> wrapper;

 class Generic<T>{

 }

 class Wrapper<T>{
  Generic<T> current;

  public void doSmth(Generic<T> generic){
  }

  public Generic<T> getCurrent(){
   return current;
  }
 }

 public void operation(){
  wrapper.doSmth(wrapper.getCurrent());
 }
}
```

The error is:

```
Error:(25, 24) java: method doSmth in class App.Wrapper<T> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: App.Generic<capture#1 of ?>
  found: App.Generic<capture#2 of ?>
  reason: actual argument App.Generic<capture#2 of ?> cannot be converted to conf.App.Generic<capture#1 of ?> by method invocation conversion
```

Comment: Can you post the actual compilation error?

Comment: @Waterbagel I have edited my post to include an error message

Comment: And maybe you could tell us what this code is supposed to; what problem you intend to solve.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compilation error should be something along the lines of "capture of ? #1 is not compatible with capture of ? #2".  The cause of this error is that `wrapper` is a `Wrapper<?>`.

The compiler sees that the `wrapper.getCurrent()` returns a `Generic<?>`, and that `wrapper.doSmth` takes a `Generic<?>` as a parameter.  But it won't equate the two `?` wildcards, even if we can see that they come from the same instance and should be the same.

One solution here is to make the `App` class generic, so you can replace the wildcard.

```
public class App<T> {
```

Because of the fact that `Generic` and `Wrapper` are inner classes, `T` is still in scope, so you don't need to declare a generic type parameter for them any more.

```
    Wrapper wrapper;

    class Generic{

    }

    class Wrapper{
        Generic current;

        public void doSmth(Generic generic){
        }

        public Generic getCurrent(){
            return current;
        }
    }

    public void operation(){
        wrapper.doSmth(wrapper.getCurrent());
    }
}
```

Comment: "But it won't equate the two ? wildcards, even if we can see that they come from the same instance and should be the same."


That was the purpose of my question. Is there any logics behind that?

Comment: The `?` could be anything, at any time.  Theoretically, something could swap out the `current` with something that has a completely different type parameter.  Perhaps that something could be a thread that makes that assignment during `operation`.  tl;dr Two `?`s can't ever be equivalent.

Comment: Well, that was the only thing I assumed. Not really happy about that. Thank you kind sir!

Comment: *"The **only** solution here"* This is not true, by the way. Can be solved by a capturing helper. (See my answer.) I got to this question late but at least you should know this.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a job for a [capturing helper](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html).

```
public void operation() {
    operationImpl(wrapper);
}

private static <T> void operationImpl(Wrapper<T> wrapper) {
    wrapper.doSmth(wrapper.getCurrent());
}
```

No other change required. The helper captures the type of `wrapper` so we can be sure `getCurrent` returns the same type as `doSmth` accepts.

---

The reason this error happens is that each time a type with a wildcard is referred to, a distinct type is assumed for that specific point in the expression (called 'capture'):

```
    Wrapper<?> wrapper = ...;

//  each capture for T is assumed distinct from each other
//  vvvvvvv        vvvvvvv
    wrapper.doSmth(wrapper.getCurrent());
```

The fact that the references point to the same instance is irrelevant to the way capture is specified. The compiler is not required to account for that and something like this can also happen

```
Wrapper<?> wrapper = new Wrapper<String>();
wrapper.doSmth((wrapper = new Wrapper<Float>()).getCurrent());
```

where `T` can change mid-expression.